# How to restrict samba shared files access in web browser?

Tags: linux, http, samba, centos6, apache-2.4

I have configured samba to share the files.But i want to restrict these shared files are showing except authorized users in the web browser.

for ex:

My smb.conf file is

```
[Creative]
        printable = no
        writable = yes
        path = /mnt/project/Creative
        write list = +staff
        Comment = Creative
        valid users = creative, admin
```

I don't want to show this "creative" folder except my valid users in my web browser.How to do it?

Comment: What's a web browser got to do with it?

Comment: Niether did I get the 'web browser' part!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query, then you want to your share to be accessbile to only a selected user(s). Try this:

```
[Creative]
        Comment = Creative
        path = /mnt/project/Creative
        valid users = @valid-smb-sys-user1, @valid-smb-sys-user2
        write list = @valid-smb-sys-user1, @valid-smb-sys-user2
        read list = @valid-smb-sys-user1, @valid-smb-sys-user2
        browseable = No
```

Make sure valid-smb-sys-user1 and valid-smb-sys-user2 are system and samba users.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to see those samba-directory files on a web browser (i.e. http://), if your shared directory is `/var/www/html`, you are running default Apache web service with (default) `DocumentRoot` pointing to the same directory and have indexes allowed in `httpd.conf`